# Render a blank response (Django Template Language)

Tags: django, django-templates

i want print the name of a given post list but it render an blank response..

Below is the code of `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

post = [
        {
        'name':'Abc,
        'dob':'01/01/1998'
        },

        {
        'name':'Xyz',
        'dob':'24/01/1993'
        }
    ]

def home(requests):

    return render(requests,'app1/home.html',dict(post))
```

Content of `home.html`

```
{% for item in post %}
        <p>name is {{ item.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

here it display the blank response instead of printing the name..So how can i fix this issue ?

What i tried is created another variable and pass it to the home.html

```
views.py

def home(requests):
     context = {
         'posts':post
     }
return render(requests,'app1/home.html',context)
```

```
home.html 

{% for item in posts %}
        <p>name is {{ item.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Above code gives the expected result..

Answer (score 0):

The values in the template are accessed by keys. To do this, you need to declare it, in this case it is 'context', in your second case it is 'posts':

```
def clinics_index(request):
    post = [
        {
            'name': 'Abc',
            'dob': '01/01/1998'
        },

        {
            'name': 'Xyz',
            'dob': '24/01/1993'
        }
    ]

    return render(request, 'app1/home.html', {'context': post})
```

templates

```
{% for item in context %}
        <p>name is {{ item.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: ```return render(requests, 'app1/home.html', dict(post))```                                                                                   Templates                                                                                                                                                                                               ```{% for item in post %}
        <p>name is {{ item.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```is it possible without using context variable with this way it render a blank response....

Comment: if you print: print(dict(post)), it will be: {'name': 'dob'}. Why are you not satisfied with access with the declared key 'context'?